# Corda: Transaction occurrence notification to a non-participant node

Tags: corda

Is there a way that a node can be notified on just the occurrence of a transaction between two different parties and not actually be able to view the details of the transaction? For example, in a simple trade finance use case, is it possible for the export bank to know that a sales contract has been agreed upon between the seller and the buyer before approving the letter of credit received from the import bank? Am assuming that the export bank is not party to the sales contract transaction and hence does not need to sign it.

Comment: please improve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `FlowLogic.send` can send any type of information, not just transactions. So as part of your flow, include a call to `send` that sends a message to the export bank.

The message could just be a normal string, or perhaps a string signed by both parties (to prove that they have indeed agreed a transaction, and it's not just the buyer/seller lying to the export bank).